# What is an ExpatError?

Tags: python, xml

I've been playing around with parsing XML with Python, and I've found that making a spelling mistake in my XML tags raises an `ExpatError`. Since I don't think my code is residing in a foreign country, to what does an `ExpatError` refer, in general?

Misspelled Code:

```
minidom.parseString("<people><pesron>Dan</person><person>John</person></people>")
```

Results In:

```
ExpatError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9c00296c48cb> in <module>()
----> 1 minidom.parseString("<people><pesron>Dan</person><person>John</person></people>")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.pyc in parseString(string, parser)
   1928     if parser is None:
   1929         from xml.dom import expatbuilder
-> 1930         return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
   1931     else:
   1932         from xml.dom import pulldom

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.pyc in parseString(string, namespaces)
    938     else:
    939         builder = ExpatBuilder()
--> 940     return builder.parseString(string)
    941 
    942 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.pyc in parseString(self, string)
    221         parser = self.getParser()
    222         try:
--> 223             parser.Parse(string, True)
    224             self._setup_subset(string)
    225         except ParseEscape:

ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 1, column 21
```

Comment: The underlying XML parsing library is called [Expat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html).

Comment: Interesting. I guess it's just a play on XML… I was hoping it had a more clever origin story.

Comment: eXPaT == XML Parser Toolkit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing up and expanding on the comments to the question:

[`ExpatError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html#xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError) is the type of exception raised when [expat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html) reports an error. expat is the Python Standard Library's XML parsing module.

[`minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html), Python's minimal implementation of the Document Object Model interface, uses expat internally to parse the XML input when `minidom.parseString()` is called.

The typo in the input XML left it with a `<pesron>` tag that is not closed, triggering expat to indicate this by throwing the `ExpatError`.

As to the origin of the name expat, rather than being a reference to "expatriate" in English, it is a shortened version of the module's description: (E)Xml PArser Toolkit.